# conventional-github-releaser doesn't pick up CHANGELOG.md as Github release description

Tags: git, github, npm, github-actions

I'm using `standard-version` (version 9.3.2) to manage the version of my npm package, as well as generating a CHANGELOG.md. This works fine as it seems.

Additionally to this, I want to create a Github release when the version tag is pushed to git. So I have created the following Github Action:

```
name: Continuous deployment (NPM)

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Build and deploy NPM package
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure node for npmjs.org as registry
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - run: npm run release:create-github-release
        env:
          CONVENTIONAL_GITHUB_RELEASER_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}

      - name: Publish package on npmjs.org
        run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

There is a step where I call `npm run release:create-github-release`, which runs `"release:create-github-release": "conventional-github-releaser -p angular"`. A release is generated, but unfortunately it doesn't contain the `CHANGELOG.md` which was previously generated and is committed to the repository at the time of running the mentioned Github Action. It looks like this:

[image: Faulty Github Release]

My question is: Why doesn't `conventional-github-releaser` pick up my `CHANGELOG.md`?

The whole project can be found here: https://github.com/openscript-ch/gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following could be a guess (based on docs I read about `conventional-github-releaser` and `actions/checkout`), so I'm not 100% sure:

When you use `actions/checkout@v2` it sets to default `fetch-depth: 1` which does a shallow checkout of your repository i.e. single commit is fetched by default (btw this you can see in you GHA as well, I attached a snapshot) and this could be most likely the reason why `conventional-github-releaser` couldn't pickup previous content of `CHANGELOG.md` as that command only "...generates a GitHub Release based on commits since the last semver tag...". When you set this explicitly to `fetch-depth: 0` it fetches all git history for all branches and tags. Try and let me know as I'm interested what's the outcome.

REF:

- https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v2
- https://github.com/ckeditor/conventional-github-releaser#quick-start

[image]

Comment: Spot on! :) I would have never found this. Thank you.